# Kotlin: How sort a array N x 2 or 2 connected array?

Tags: android, sorting, kotlin, matrix

I have a n x 2 array or 2 independent onedimensional arrays but connected. I would like to sort one of the vectors (or one of the 2 columns of the n x 2 array) and sort the other accordingly.

It’s no use saying that I should create a class and make a class array, because I want to have ready access to the 2 vectors.

This is scientific programming, so I don't want to have to extract number arrays  from class arrays. It is very inefficient.

I believe that or I will have to do the sorting  by hand, because apparently I cannot use a   `comparator` function model because it apparently does not give me access to the indexes of an individual value exchange, that is being made depending on the result of the comparison.

Is there no way or is there a good solution to this problem?

Comment: How about sorting a one-dimensional array of indexes into the real arrays? It starts with values 0, 1, 2,... and the comparator uses the index numbers to access items of the real array and compares them. Finally you have "sorted" index numbers which you can use to reorder both real arrays.

Comment: There is really a good idea! I will wait a little bit if appears some direct solution, like exists in other languages like Python.

Comment: It's also possible get an double array from a sorted class array, using `map`. But it's not a natural solution.